# How can I make my linear gradient to work?

Tags: css

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(linear,left top, left 
bottom,from(#5ba654), to(#ADE19E));
```

I`m not sure what I am doing wrong here...please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code will only work in a WebKit browser hence the `-webkit` tag.
There's a [really handy CSS gradient generator here](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) that I used to generate the code below.

```css
.gradient {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%
  background: #5ba654;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5ba654 0%, #ade19e 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5ba654 0%,#ade19e 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5ba654 0%,#ade19e 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5ba654', endColorstr='#ade19e',GradientType=0 );
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#5ba654, #ADE19E);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#5ba654, #ADE19E);
background: linear-gradient(#5ba654, #ADE19E);
```

Syntax: `background: linear-gradient(direction, color1, color2, ...);`

Default `direction` is top to bottom.